# Iteratively changing dates in URLs

Tags: python, loops, url

I'm having trouble building a logic/algorithm that creates a date, adds it to the URL and then when I create another URL, it will contain the next date.

It should iterate through every day of every month of every year (that's why I thought of the nested for loops).

Note that I only have one variable for date because I want the start and end dates to be the same.

```
# Setting range of years, months and days to be iterated through in the URL later
YYYY = []
years = range(2016, 2021)
for yyyy in years:
    YYYY.append(yyyy)

MM = []
months = range(1, 13)
for mm in months:
    MM.append(mm)

DD = []
days = range (1, 32)
for dd in days:
    DD.append(dd)

    
# Create iterating logic with i, j and k t define which year, month and day will be added to the URL
for i in YYYY:
    for j in MM:
        for k in DD:
            True

            
# start_date and e_date are the same, so we just define 'date'
date = str(YYYY[i]) + '-' + str(MM[j]) + '-' + str(DD[k])
print(date)


# Create URL with the date variable so it can be iterated through
URL = ('https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' +
       date + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date + '&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US')
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is I need to download individual datasets from each of the dates. And the way I will perform the download is by editing the date for which I want the dataset directly in the URL. Therefore, I have one URL per date. After I have the URLs with the correct dates, I add them to a list and move on from there, performing code that downloads the dataset for each item (URL) in the URL list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `datetime` and `timedelta` objects to make a generator to produce the URLs to iterate over:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_url():
    date = datetime(2016,1,1)
    while date < datetime(2020,12,31):
        yield 'https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' + \
               date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US'
        date += timedelta(days=1)
    
i = 0
for url in get_url():
    i += 1
    if i < 3 or i > 10:
        print(url)
    if i > 12:
        break
```

Output:

```
https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=2016-01-01&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-01&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US
https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=2016-01-02&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-02&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US
https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=2016-01-11&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-11&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US
https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=2016-01-12&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-12&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US
https://movement.uber.com/explore/atlanta/travel-times/query?si=1074&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=2016-01-13&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-13&dt[dr][ed]=2016-01-19&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US
```

Comment: That's great! There is just one thing though: I don't understand the second part of your code (from i = 0). Could you explain in a little more detail? I don't understand why the dates in the printed URLs jump from day 2 to day 11.

Comment: @LuizScheuer it was just to demonstrate how to use the generator, I didn't want to print out all the dates that the generator would produce (5 years worth). You can ignore all that code and put your own code after `for url in get_url():` or you can do something like `urls = get_url()` and then use `next(urls)` to get the next URL

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for that. Another question: is the generator taking into consideration the correct number of days for each month? For example, February sometimes has 29 days, sometimes 28 days. Does this code know and take this into account?

Comment: @LuizScheuer yes - adding a timedelta of 1 day to a datetime object will always give the correct result.